# Benchmark XSLT performance

Tags: .net, xslt, benchmarking, xslcompiledtransform

I am trying to benchmark two versions of an XSLT. Currently I use Visual Studio to debug since xml transformations which are invoked from a .NET component. VS 2010 is the IDE I use for development.

Only clue I get is from the output window (below is an e.g.):

> ﻿Stylesheet load time: 656.2 ms
>     Stylesheet JIT time: 11.18 ms
>     Stylesheet execution time: 177.8 ms

I believe I just need to be bothered with "Stylesheet execution time" but not sure if these values do reflect the actual capability of the XSL since that seems to be continuously varying for every run.

I would like to know if there is a reliable way to benchmark XSL. Any hands-on experience share in benchmarking XSL with .NET runtime would be helpful.

Comment: The best way to keep it near true is to make sure the xslt is compiled using the compilation options. If you dont each execution time will be different the first time.

Comment: You can use the XslCompiledTransform to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been asked before in stackoverflow you can see the original question here: [How do I profile and optimize an XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434976/how-do-i-profile-and-optimize-an-xslt)

Below is a snippet from the accepted answer:

> which XSLT engine are you using? If you are using the .NET engine and
>   Visual Studio you could use the XSLT profiler integrated into Visual
>   Studio which is a very useful.
>
> Other excellent profiling tools are Altova's XML Spy and Oxygen.
>
> If you would post your XSLT it would be easier to tell you where
>   possible bottlenecks are. In general be careful with XPath expressions
>   such as '//', preceding::* and following::*. Some more rules and
>   best-practices:
>
> 1. Avoid repeated use of `"//item"`.
> 2. Don't evaluate the same node-set more than once; save it in a variable.
> 3. Avoid `<xsl:number>` if you can. For example, by using position().
> 4. Use `<xsl:key>`, for example to solve grouping problems.
> 5. Avoid complex patterns in template rules. Instead, use
>       within the rule.
> 6. Be careful when using the `preceding[-sibling]` or
>      `following[-sibling]` axes. This often
>      indicates an algorithm with n-squared
>      performance.
> 7. Don't sort the same node-set more than once. If necessary, save it
>      as a result tree fragment and access
>      it using the `node-set()` extension
>      function.
> 8. To output the text value of a simple `#PCDATA` element, use
>      `<xsl:value-of>` in preference to
>      `<xsl:apply-templates>`.
>
> (from [http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect4/N9883.html#d15756e150][4])
>
> Originally from : https://stackoverflow.com/users/40347/0xa3

I would make sure the XSLT you can calling is compiled before running that way you are not getting mixed metrics from the compilation process that happens every time.

You can use the XslCompiledTransform class to ensure the XSLT is compiled before running. Very important that you do not dispose of that and reuse the transform other wise every time you create the object again it will recompile and take a random time to do it.

There is an interesting article here: http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/07/14/xsltperf.html called XSLT Performance in .NET

It goes on to benchmark XSLT transform in .Net to other xslt engines.

My experience working with XSLT is that has been very fast most unless custom function were added to the transform eg. calling custom code that was not performante usually small to medium sheets should run pretty fast specially of you dont have many imports and function calls.

If you are really worried there is a brilliant article from MSDN Enterprise Patterns and Practices with a section about performance on XML and XSLT transformation.

The article is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649152.aspx

The section I am talking about is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647804.aspx

Microsoft did a post on Benchmarking XSLT which is an interesting read.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/antosha/archive/2006/07/24/xslcompiledtransform-performance-beating-msxml-4-0.aspx

There also a way to pre-compile style sheet into code so the xslt transforms are only loaded and not parsed at all.

You can find information about this here: (Using Precompiled XSLT in .NET) http://my-tech-talk.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/using-precompiled-xslt-in-net.html

Comment: Thanks. I am taking a look at it. btw I am currently using XslCompiledTransform but see varying results.

Comment: Can you confirm that the input is always the same and are you keeping a static version of the XslCompiledTransform ? It is no use if you dispose of the object after creating it the first time. Other wise you are recompiling it everytime you create a new object

Comment: I do use dispose and that could be the reason. I am continuing to test and validate, will keep posted.

Comment: I tried modifying the code and its still seems to vary. I have checked this with the VS 2010 inbuilt XSL processor (not via. code) and that shows varying result for every run. I assume the only option is to go with an average of Stylesheet execution time.

Comment: do you have any external function calls on the xslt?

Comment: Not using any external functions.

Comment: Is the data the data on each run?

Comment: Yep its the same data but IDE keeps reporting different execution time. I wonder if Microsoft had anything at all. I do not see much of information with respect to that although they have big plans to support XSL.

Comment: Please use a stopwatch instead. The class in system diagnostics

Comment: I tried adding a stopwatch but that too seems to be varying for every run. But its evident that on an average one among the two XSLTs I use has at least 25x performance increase than the other.

Comment: Ok . hmm may be you should review that one. Out of interest why are you using xslt

Comment: Data transformation of moderately big user list. Nothing much interesting in it but I was just trying out push/pull models and ways to better XSLT programming. Seems I got a little more with all those resources you guys pointed out. Thank you!.

Comment: I have found some additional info and updated my answer. glad you find it helpful

Comment: Yes that is related but I was looking more towards Benchmarking techniques/tools. btw I had read the article earlier and that seems to be coming from @Michael Kay (assume Mike Kay is him :)).

Comment: The one quoted above from http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect4/N9883.html#d15756e150.

Comment: Not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look at the paper we (Michael Kay and Debbie Lockett) published recently at XML London, see

http://xmllondon.com/2014/xmllondon-2014-proceedings.pdf

which describes some of the pitfalls that arise when benchmarking XSLT performance. See also the project on Github

https://github.com/Saxonica/XT-Speedo

To get repeatable results it's essential to run a transformation repeatedly and take an average.

Comment: Yeah I resorted to the idea of taking an average but I was not sure of above values - MSDN provides no details about those. For some reason I am unable to access http://xmllondon.com/2014/xmllondon-2014-proceedings.pdf now. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like there is no solution from Microsoft except for the basic IDE provided values I quoted above. I am not sure if there are any other products like XMLSpy or StylusStudio which offers such features.

Comment: XT-Speedo includes drivers designed to take measurements for a number of XSLT processors including Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform. You can find another copy of our paper at http://www.saxonica.com/papers/xmllondon-2014mhk.pdf

Comment: Cool, that's a pretty exhaustive paper. Will check out XT-Speedo. Thank you for those pointers!.

Answer (score 0):

To conclude I am summarizing this for a quick reference for someone who might refer to this thread in the future:

For .NET the easiest way to benchmark is to use XSLT profiler. But the catch is it's only available with Microsoft Visual Studio Team System with Profiling Tools installed.

Another good option available is XT-Speedo an open source tool from Saxonica. Try it.

Apart from this for a quick-and-dirty assessment you can run multiple transformation of your XSLs and use a simple StopWatch Tick to get an average which may be sufficient in most cases.